# Now that the production version CiviCRM 4.7 released can Drupal 8.03 be used with it for production sites?

Tags: drupal-8

Now that the production version CiviCRM 4.7 released can Drupal 8.03 be used with it for production sites? When do you anticipate a stable production version with drupal 8.0?